# Looping keyboard effect

Tags: python-2.7, printing

I am trying to write a script that reads from a text file and outputs the content using a type writer effect. I have been able to acheive this using the following code

```
import sys
from time import sleep


f=open("test.txt", "r")

words = f 
for char in words:
    sleep(0.5)
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Which works, however I would like to turn this into a loop so that the text  prints, the screen (output) is cleared, a one second pause and then the text prints again (with same keyboard effect).

I have tried this

```
import sys
from time import sleep


f=open("test.txt", "r")

while True: 
    words = f
    for char in words:
        sleep(0.5)
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()

        break
```

But this prints the text and then 'hangs' at the end.

All suggestions welcome!

Comment: because you get stuck in a `while True` loop... what are you trying to achieve? clear after each line?

Comment: Just updated OP @Tomerikoo yes I would like it to clear at the end of the output, pause a second and then print again.